# How to compute the sine of huge numbers

Tags: trigonometry, programming

For several days, I've been wondering how it would be possible to compute the sine of huge numbers like `100000!` (radians). I obviously don't use `double` but `cpp_rational` from the boost multiprecision library. But I can't simply do `100000! mod 2pi` and then use the builtin function `sinl` (I don't need more than 10 decimal digits..) as I'd need several million digits of pi to compute this accurately.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why?  Why is this necessary?

Comment: You chould try to use the following relationship: $\Gamma(n+0.5)=\frac{2n!}{n!4^n}\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: $100000!=31415*100000*99999!/31415≒pi*k$. So $sin100000!≒0.000$.

Comment: Applying the taylor-series won't work. $1)$ The alternating signs lead to numerical instability $2)$ we need too many terms. It seems that we need a program with high precision-calculation and cannot compute , for example $sin(10^{10^{10^{10}}})$

Comment: $(10^5)!$ has $456,574$ digits. Do you need the sine for even larger numbers ? You need less tha a million digits for $sin((10^5)!)$

Comment: @TakahiroWaki This approximation is far too inaccurate to calculate $sin((10^5)!)$

Comment: For those who are interested : $(10^5)!\ modulo\ 2\pi=4.33131820813936408660\ \cdot\ \cdot\ \cdot$

Comment: So, the sine is $-0.9282669319268813746181175648\cdot\cdot\ \cdot$, coinciding with Mario's result.

Comment: @Peter : how do you know this is a good approximation ? (how do you compute $n! \bmod 2 \pi$ in general ?)

Comment: @TakahiroWaki 31415 is not nearly enough precision considering you're multiplying it by such an astronomical number... the "small" error of $.000096\ldots$ becomes amplified to way beyond the size of $\pi$.

Comment: @user1952009 I used PARI/GP with a precision of a million digits.

Comment: @Peter : my question was : how do you know a million digit is enough for computing it with a 20 digit precision ? (and in general what is the needed precision for $\pi$ when computing $n ! \bmod 2 \pi$ with a 20 digit precision ?)

Comment: $(10^5)!$ has less than $500,000$ digits. (Since it is an integer, PARI can calculate it exactly). If we know $\pi$ with a precision of a million digits and divide $(10^5)!$ by $2\pi$, the number is a bit smaller than $(10^5)!$, so many of the digits of the fraction will be correct (It is nearly impossible that hundred thousands of nines or zeros follow). If I subtract $2\pi$ times this number from $(10^5)!$, I get the remainder and the precision will be almost the same. I see no reason why the final result should not be good to $20$ digits (In fact several hundred thousand digits)

Comment: The real challenge is to find a method to calculate $\sin(x)$ for monster numbers like $x=10^{10^{10^{10}}}$ or at least for $x=10^{10^{100}}$. Mario's answer could be a promising approach.

Comment: Problems with on chip value for pi: Intel Underestimates Error Bounds by 1.3 quintillion Intel https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/

Answer (score 15):

I believe you may be able to calculate this without obscene numbers of digits of $\pi$ if you take advantage of the fact that these are factorials. To simplify the algebra, we can calculate $a_n=e^{i(n!)}$ instead (you want the imaginary part). Then $$a_{n+1}=e^{i(n!)(n+1)}=a_n^{n+1},$$ and it's perfectly reasonable to calculate $a_{100000}$ recursively with a high-precision library.

The downside is that to start the recursion you need a very good approximation of $e^i$, and I don't know if the error dependence works out any differently than in the $\pmod{2\pi}$ approach.

But to answer your actual question, Mathematica doesn't even break a sweat with the mere million digits needed for this:

```
> Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000000}, N[Sin[100000!], 10]]

-0.9282669319
```

takes about 15 ms on my computer.

---

For calculating the sine or cosine of a large arbitrary precision *real* number $x$, the gains of this method (which are tuned for $\sin n$ for integer $n$) are mostly lost, so I would recommend your original idea of reducing the argument $\bmod 2\pi$. As has been noted, the main bottleneck is a high-precision estimation of $\pi$. Your answer will be useless unless you can at least calculate $\frac{x}{\pi}$ to within $1$ (otherwise you may as well answer "somewhere between $-1$ and $1$"), so you need at least $\log_2(x/\pi^2)$ bits of precision for $\pi$. With $x\approx100000!$, that's about $1516701$ bits or $456572$ digits. Add to this the number $a$ of bits of precision you want in the result, so about $1516734$ digits of $\pi$ to calculate $33$ bits ($\approx 10$ digits) of $\sin x$ in the range $x\approx 100000!$.

Once you have an integer $n$ such that $y=2\pi n$ is close to $x$ (ideally $|x-2\pi n|\le2\pi$, it doesn't have to be perfectly rounded), calculate $\pi$ to precision $a+\log_2(n)$, so that $y$ is known to precision $a$, and then $x-y$ is precision $a$ and $\sin x=\sin (x-y)$ can be calculated to precision $a$ as well.

Comment: If I am right, the relative error on a power is the relative error on the base times that power. So you will need to evaluate $e^i$ with $n!$ decimals.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Actually, you only need error within $\frac1{n!}$ of the target error, which means about $\log(n!)$ decimals. $n!$ decimals would truly be obscene.

Comment: you are right, my bad.

Comment: I don't actually compute the sine of a factorial but of a number _as big as_ 100000! - but anyway: how is Mathematica actually capable of computing the sine that fast?!

Comment: @OliverBorchert Actually, nothing about this method really depends on it being $n!$. I'm just taking $e^i$ to a very large integer power, which you could do just as well with other numbers by [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). The important part is that to calculate $e^{in}$ you need about $a+\log_2(n)$ bits of precision on $e^i$ to get $a$ bits at the end.

Comment: @OliverBorchert If you want to calculate the sine or cosine of a large real number, I would suggest breaking it into the form $n+x$ where $0\le x<1$ and then calculate $(e^i)^ne^{ix}$ using an $a+\log_2(n)$ bit approximation of $e^i$ and an $a$ bit approximation of $e^{ix}$ (which you can use standard sine and cosine math functions for).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro your last comment could be extremely helpful (I'll try that out). But what exactly is a? (And what is n supposed to be? log_2(100000!) is still more than a million..) Would it be possible to add this approach (and some code) - I actually don't know a lot about complex numbers - to your answer?

Comment: @OliverBorchert $a$ is the desired precision, for example you said you wanted 10 digits of precision so $a$ is about $33$ bits. I'm afraid you're on the wrong site for specific code examples, but you can calculate the product of two complex numbers via $(a+ib)(c+id)=(ac-bd)+i(ad+bc)$ - just store two real numbers of high precision and do the multiplications like that. (Many high-precision libraries already come with support for complex numbers; see if yours does.) If you have a high-precision sine and cosine, you can calculate $e^i=\cos 1+i\sin 1$.